# Extract arbitrary XML from a text file using sed

Tags: sed

I have a log file with multiple request XML snippets in it.  I am using this sed command to extract and print the request XML:

```
sed -n '/<GetCompensableProductIdentification*/,/<\/GetCompensableProductIdentification>/p' ProductIdentifierService.log
```

I want to use variables for the request start and end tags so that I can filter out any request I want.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

This might help you,

```
 sed -n 's,.*<GetCompensableProductIdentification>\(.*\)</GetCompensableProductIdentification>.*,\1,p' input
```

But I guess `xmlstarlet` is valid tool for this case,

```
 xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//GetCompensableProductIdentification' -n
```

Comment: I'd definitely go with the proper XML parsing tool, especially if the XML is complete. +1

Answer (score 1):

This script

```
sed -n '/<GetCompensableProductIdentification>/,/<\/GetCompensableProductIdentification>/p' ProductIdentifierService.log
```

should do it

The `-n`  option here suppresses the normal output. so, only, the stuff you selected will be printed.

---

To use variables, you could use the [[ shell parameter substitution ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
start_tag="<GetCompensableProductIdentification>"
end_tag="${start_tag/#</<\\/}"
sed -n "/${start_tag}/,/${end_tag}/p" ProductIdentifierService.log
```

---

That tempts you to write a script

```
# Script name - xmlparser.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
start_tag="$1"
end_tag="${start_tag/#</<\\/}"
if [ -e "$2" ] # Extra check if file exists
then
   sed -n "/${start_tag}/,/${end_tag}/p" "$2"
else
   echo " The file : $2 doesn't exists"
fi
```

Run the script like

```
./xmlparser.sh "<GetCompensableProductIdentification>"  "/path/to/log/file"
```

Comment: says ,./Log_ExtractorN[37]: end_tag="${start_tag/#</<\\/}": bad substitution

Comment: I am using korn shell (ksh)

Comment: I am running it with a script on my exceed unix terminal ,

Comment: The scripts has the following ,

Comment: #!/usr/bin/ksh

start_tag="<GetCompensableProductIdentification>"
end_tag="${start_tag/#</<\\/}"
sed -n "/${start_tag}/,/${end_tag}/p" ProductIdentifierService.log

Comment: @AbhinavSingh . What is the version of your `ksh`?

Comment: ran this command - strings /bin/ksh | grep Version | tail -2 .. results - @(#)Version 11/16/88

Comment: @AbhinavSingh : You ksh version doesn't support the parameter substitution I've used. See [\[ this \]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20966729/1620779). Please wait, Ill update

Comment: yep the end tag is now being set correctly , just removed the backtic from the overall command and the variable go set correctly.

Comment: But facing issue with sed now , it says  - sed: Function /<GetCompensableProductIdentification>/,/</GetCompensableProductIdentification>/p cannot be parsed.

Comment: @AbhinavSingh `just removed the backtic from the overall command`, You can't do that !! either do **end_tag=$(echo "$start_tag" | sed 's/^</<\//)** or do**end_tag=\`echo "$start_tag" | sed 's/^</<\//\`**, note the second one has backticks..

Comment: both doesn't work for me , but this one works  -  end_tag=`echo "$start_tag" | sed 's/^</<\//'`

Comment: end_tag=`echo "$start_tag" | sed 's/^</<\//'`

Comment: the bacticks getting removed in the comment , theres one before echo and the other one at the end

Comment: Could you please help with the sed command  -  as it says , sed: Function /<GetCompensableProductIdentification>/,/</GetCompensableProductIdentification>/p cannot be parsed.

Comment: yeah I understand :)

Comment: I have used the one -"  or do end_tag=`echo "$start_tag" | sed 's/^</<\//`, note the second one has backticks.. – sjsam 13 mins ago"  , this one works

Comment: @AbhinavSingh Please try this **end_tag=\`echo "$start_tag" | sed 's|^<|<\\\/|'\`**

Comment: @AbhinavSingh : you need a literal **\** there, so three **\** are required, one for escaping **\** and one for escaping **\**

Comment: dis not get you

Comment: @AbhinavSingh : Didn't understand. Did you try the last one i gave you?

Comment: Please move this conversation to a discussion chat. Also please try and cleanup the above chats and move  anything you can into the actual question and/or delete it if it's no longer necessary.

Comment: tag=GetCompensableProductIdentification
start_tag="<"$tag
end_tag = "<\/"$tag">"

sed -n "/${start_tag}/,/${end_tag}/p" ProductIdentifierService.log